# Is there a way to alias a specific interface ip?

Tags: linux, debian, ethernet, interface

I've got a VCS running on debian as prod server, and due to some hypervisor issues it had to be rebooted/migrated/updated several times in the past week.

Because i'm running my app using docker containers, i can't just pass `localhost` for it to connect to my local postgres, so i'm using the `ens2` ip instead.

```
ens2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.12.174.3  netmask 255.255.255.254  broadcast 10.12.174.3
        inet6 fe80::dc1c:14ff:fe51:5002  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2001:bc8:4740:205::1  prefixlen 127  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether de:1c:14:51:50:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 37139  bytes 4801851 (4.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 39791  bytes 35291408 (33.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

But with every reboot that ip changes, and i have to manually go and change it in env vars so my app can reach the db again, which i'm sure you'll agree is not very practical.

So here is my question: is there a way to automatically assign an alias, pretty much like `localhost`, to this specific interface?

I guess i could still try and parse the `ifconfig` output but i'd rather ask first for an actual solution

Thanks for your time guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS.

Maintain a record for the application to use, perhaps `appdb.prod.example.org`. As this is a service name, consider creating a CNAME to the host currently running it.

Update a name in DNS each time a host gets an IP.  For example, AAAA record called `container1.example.org` containing `2001:bc8:4740:205::1`. How exactly to do this depends on your numbering scheme and DNS configuration.  Static IPs can be entered as soon as they are allocated. DHCP hooks can be used to update DNS. And there exists software to watch every interface for IP changes and do an nsupdate, such as  [autoddns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/347758/86954).

---

Do not use ifconfig on Linux, not for new scripts. [It has been obsolete for at least 11 years.](https://lwn.net/Articles/710533/)

Comment: Oh wow, 11 years. That's a lot  I feel a little bit outdated here. I'll have a look to this autoddns, it sounds like what i need, thank you !

Comment: In addition, I gave the other examples like static and DHCP to show this depends on your address allocation methods and DNS environment.

Answer (score 0):

Could always use:

```
alias ip="hostname -I"
```

Comment: Yeah i could `cut` the ip out of this easily but then it's tricky is to keep it up to date in `/etc/hosts` every time it changes... I was rather wondering about a "legit" way to refer to a given interface 

Comment: Regarding -I, per the manual `Do not make any assumptions about the order of the output.`  A robust script would parse the results to see which is IPv4 and which is IPv6.